# snap - how to grant /tmp access to snap chromium?

Tags: permissions, chromium, snap

I usually use `/tmp` when I download files that I need just this one time so that they're be deleted automatically. But snap chromium sees `/tmp/snap.chromium/tmp` as `/tmp` and for the worst of it, the user hasn't permission to open this directory. I know almost nothing of how snap works and am wondering if there is a way to grant `/tmp` access to some snap application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Chromium suddenly access any partition except for /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home)

Comment: @DanDascalescu I can not find any snap plug for `/tmp` directory to connect to chromium snap.

Comment: You don't need any plug, that's the idea in that answer. Any path works.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Do you mean the workaround with unsnapped instance of chromium or `snap:connect` one?

Comment: Right, I meant to link to [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home/1251289#1251289). I guess that could be called "unsnapped".

Answer (score 3):

I also find this quite annoying. The solution offered here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1851250 is to mount a tmpfs under your home directory.

There is more information here: [Why can't Chromium suddenly access any partition except for /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home), along with some other solutions such as installing a non-snap package if you're interested.

Comment: Can you described a little more the way how to solve this issue by explaining each steps? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1192185/edit) your answer

Comment: @damadam I think it would be best asked as a separate question. As a pointer, this answer helped me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192458/179655.

Comment: Add this link in [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1192185/edit) instead of comment, I just say that in order to avoid your answer to be flagged as link-only answer (which aren't well-received in general)

Comment: @damadam It's not a link-only answer. I've included the solution, which is to mount a tmpfs under your home directory. If you're unsure how to do that I think it would be best asked as a separate question.

Comment: Problem in your answer is that you just add links without explaining essentials interessant parts of these, which is not how AskUbuntu works; I just recommend you to improve your answer by extracting essential steps (that could be interesting for you, better is an answer, higher are chance to upvote it)

Comment: @damadam I thank you for your concern regarding my reputation, however, I believe I've included the essential information from the links I provided. I've edited my answer to include a solution from the other question that I linked to. Neither of them is ideal, but, IMO, the problem is really in the design of the snap system, and I don't have a feasible solution to that.

Comment: @damadam as to explaining the steps I took in detail - other users have raised security concerns about the method I used. I'm not conversant enough about GNU to evaluate the pros and cons of the approach, so don't want to propagate a potentially dangerous solution. That's why I recommend that it be asked as a separate question.

Comment: You can explain what you write in comment by editing your answer, it would be a good answer, even if it didn't solve totally OP issue

Comment: snap is awful...

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least for the time being. But the answer should not call this a “solution”.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into exactly that problem.
It took me some time to understand what was going on as the path `/tmp` appears in the `save as...` window (instead of the real path `/tmp/snap.chromium/tmp`).

Comment: I knew this but it doesn't help me access my files any easier. `/tmp/snap.chromium/tmp` needs extra permission to access besides when I click on downloaded files, associated programs does not prompt to open the file (this I don't know why).