# Verify snap application runs in a container

Tags: 18.04, security, snap, container

I'm new to snap (`snapd`), but from what I have read the snap support sanboxed app environments out of the box ([Snap vs Flatpak vs AppImage)](https://linuxhint.com/snap_vs_flatpak_vs_appimage/).

**Question:** Is it there a way for me to verify that the application itself actually is "sandboxed"? Can I verify that it is running in a container, and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Snap applications can run in various confinement models, *strict* which is default, and *classic* which allows far more liberal access to your system (ie. can read & write to your file-system much like *deb* packages can). Don't forget one *snap* confinement model differs to another.  https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement

Comment: For `chromium` (browser) try and upload a file to a website and navigate what looks like your *filesystem*, at the same time comparing to what's really in those directories. You'll see note the files don't match, as the *snap* is restricted to a *fs* that exists within the *snap* itself. Yes you can add extra directories via `snap connect` etc, but only within certain limits. (Chromium runs in a *strict* confinement model)

Comment: Hmmm, ok. So the snap way of solving this "sandboxing" is to give each application an own filesystem? I didn't quite get the `chromium` example: If I upload a file, I would think the application (`chromium`) would copy that file to its dedicated fs, if that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, with chromium you're uploading a file to a website (any website), and exploring your 'local' file system looking for a file to upload.. If you navigate to directories where you know a file is located (outside of $HOME; chromium can read any $HOME directory) you'll quickly discover the file-system the snap sees is pretty sparse & empty and doesn't match your real file-system.. `snap connect` can add /mnt/ and /media/ access, but that's as far as the confinement allows. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home

Comment: Ok, yeah - that makes sense. Can only access files in `HOME`-directory. Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify the snap confinement mode with the command `snap info --verbose` , e.g.

```
snap info --verbose chromium
name:    chromium
...
notes:               
...
  confinement:       strict
  devmode:           false
...
```

List your installed snaps with `snap list`.

Comment: Yes, that's the `confinement` value, but I have read that Ubuntu (`X11`) does not support the isolation that snap comes with.

Comment: The confinement value confirms that your app is sandboxed, and has only access to specific parts of the system as specified by the allowed "interfaces". If you want to challenge something you have read, then ask that directly in a new question. Your current question is "verify it runs in a container".