# Launch specific Chromium profile in Lubuntu 20.04 (LXQt)

Tags: lubuntu, snap, chromium, lxqt

In LXDE we could create desktop launcher shortcuts that would handle this. I used to use this for example within a desktop shortcut file:

```
chromium-browser --profile-directory="Default"
```

Somehow this doesn't work anymore, and in fact launching Chromium in this way directly from terminal fails too. Is there some new way to do this? Do Snaps maybe require a new syntax for launching in this way from the terminal?

Comment: You can `chromium-browser --help` to view the details for the program, sorry as I never used the feature your asking about I'm unsure of what you want, however be aware when the snap starts, it sees the containerized file system and not your real file system, so if you've prepared files on your real *fs* for it, they may not be seen thus could be your issue.  By default it has access to your home, a few other directories can be added via `snap connect` commands (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home) or in squashfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the answer and it was pretty simple:

```
snap run chromium --profile-directory="Profile 2"
```