# Cannot find files downloaded in /tmp/ folder

Tags: filesystem, chromium, downloads

I download some file using chromium into the /tmp/ directory.
Then, in a terminal, I look into /tmp/ and the file is NOT there.
If I try to download it again, it is already listed in the /tmp/ directory (since it was already downloaded there, whatever 'there' means at this point).

Could it be that the download interface and the terminal refer to two different /tmp/ directories?

The interface for downloading the file is a graphical interface which offers the choice "Other Locations", and under this choice it offers "Computer", which shows the contents of a typical root (/) directory (usr, bin, home, var, etc.).
From there I choose /tmp/ to download the file there.
But thereafter, typing ls /tmp in a terminal does not show the file being there.

Any idea?

Comment: There are only one /tmp on your system. Please describe exactly what you are doing, commands and maybe screen-dumps of GUI tool.

Comment: You may be running a _snap_ utility!

Comment: If you open Nautilus and then select Recent, if the file is listed there you can right click it with your mouse and then select Open item location which will take you to where it is stored.

Comment: We don't know your OS & release.  On recent releases, `chromium-browser` is a *snap* meaning it doesn't have full access to your file-system outside of $HOME, or (`snap-connect`) certain directories... so start with what OS & release you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my initial post because a crucial word "NOT" was missing in the second sentence. More information about OS used & stuff coming.

Comment: The OS used is Ubuntu 20.04. Chromium is Version 87.0.4280.88 (Build officiel) snap (64 bits). Now the 'snap' hypothesis given by @guiverc starts to make real sense...

Comment: And @FedonKadifeli

Comment: The version of chromium doesn't matter, however yes you'll be using the *snap* version (use `snap list` to view your installed snaps). Snaps can have different confinement restrictions, *classic* can access your file-system (lowest level of security), however all other levels mean they see a *pretend* file-system that isn't your real one as the run *confined* (excluding $HOME or your user directory; that's real, and if you've `snap-connect` /media, /mnt they an be accessed too). The /tmp seen by `chromium` snap is **NOT** the /tmp you see a terminal/file-manager etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of chromium doesn't matter, however yes you'll be using the *snap* version (use `snap list` to view your installed snaps). eg. my system shows

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   snap list
Name               Version                     Rev    Tracking       Publisher         Notes
chromium           87.0.4280.88                1424   latest/stable  canonical✓        -
```

Snaps can have different confinement restrictions, *classic* can access your file-system (lowest level of security), however all other levels mean they see a *pretend* file-system that isn't your real one as they run *confined* (excluding $HOME or your user directory; that's real, and if you've `snap-connect` /media, /mnt they an be accessed too).

The /tmp seen by `chromium` snap is **NOT** the /tmp you see a terminal/file-manager etc.

Comment: If you need/want more information about the `snap-connect` I mention; see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home/1184374#1184374

Comment: Thanks this fully explains the issue. Now I'll check the given resources to see how to make chromium download in the "true" /tmp, if at all possible.

Comment: The *snap* confinement model is selected at *build* time but the builder (https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement) and I don't believe you'll be able to change anything about `chromium` because it's not built to be *classic* confinement *snap* (that would not be wise security-wise for a web browser, but would have provided full access to your real file-system).  Builds of *snaps* and `/tmp` have had issues (see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/temporarydirectory-and-how-to-manage-access-to-tmp/10176) but that's for developers (and won't be useful to you)

Comment: I use `chromium` (as evidenced by my partial `snap list`command; on my *hirsute* system) and a `lsof |grep chromium |grep tmp` does show some results (ie. list open files.. show chromium .. show only tmp`).. maybe you'll find files there of use, but I very much doubt it...

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for the additional information