# Why is host-hunspell so big?

Tags: firefox, virtualization, hunspell

`lsblock` on an osboxes Ubuntu VM return this:

```
sda      8:0    0   500G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 220.6G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                /
├─sda2   8:2    0   286M  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0    95M  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0   8.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda5   8:5    0 270.1G  0 part /home
```

The 220.6G size of host-hunspell raises concern?
Why would it be so big? Is this a strange problem with the osboxes VM?

Comment: You've allocated 220GB to your `/` system, which is also accessible (*within confinement restrictions anyway*) by the `firefox` snap; the snap isn't using additional space though; it's just a `mount`.

Comment: @guiverc Please explain it more accessibly (to new users)? I didn't understand the answer. I did notice it appears that there are two mountpoints on that device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *file-system* mounted on `/` is ~220GB

That *file-system* (sda1 or drive SDA & partition 1) is mounted twice, firstly as the root (`/`) file-system, and secondly so it can be accessed by `firefox` (if you want to save/upload files*).

You'll find however that not all of `/` can be accessed from within `firefox`, as most snap packages run *confined* thus have only limited access to your `/` file-system, even though in theory the mount could allow for it.

For my current Ubuntu system, I have the following

```
guiverc@d7080-next:~/.config/liferea$   lsblk
(some details redacted for length)
├─sda5   8:5    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda6   8:6    0  97.4G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell


guiverc@d7080-next:~/.config/liferea$   df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                        1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda6                     96G   39G   52G  43% /
tmpfs                        7.8G  301M  7.5G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        7.8G   54M  7.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5                    511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        1.6G  104K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

ie. you'll note it's the same, my ~96GB partition mounted as my root (`/`) is also mounted for use by the `firefox` snap package.

It's not strange, nor is it a concern (*not ~220GB of wasted space for you, ~96GB for me*), it's just how it works,

Comment: Not sure it's well explained sorry, others could I'm sure explain it better.

Comment: When you said upload, did you mean download?

Comment: I think the part that puzzles me the most as a new user is multiple mountpoints for one partition.
Can you elaborate on the concept of mounting twice? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if you realize it yet, but *snap* packages (running *confined*) can access your $HOME (/home/$USER directory) but not your base file-system; the instead see a *squashfs* version of it; or the *snap* itself & that's what you explore if looking for files in `firefox` to upload for example. I have various network shares appearing in my `df -h` that I redacted, they are mounted off `/` as I prefer to avoid typing.. ie. `/de2900` is a directory for a network share.. That is outside of where *confined* snaps can go, thus I can't save/upload from `firefox` or `chromium` there.

Comment: To explore that I'll provide a question on this site where I used tried & failed (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303845/cannot-find-files-downloaded-in-tmp-folder/1303991#1303991). Snaps can also access `/mnt` and `/media`. As I didn't want to type `/mnt/de2900/` everywhere, I mount that share twice; it's found in `/de2900/` where I've had it for years, plus a more restricted mount is found in `/mnt/de2900/` which the *snap* packages can use. I've added more restrictions to the mount in `/mnt/` as I'll be using that from browsers (firefox/chromium) but that was my choice.

Comment: I'm using the `/de2900` as example... with my mounting it twice as it means I didn't need to type `/mnt/de2900/lan/un....` & saved myself four characters for all mounts, but can still upload/download from browsers that run *confined* too using that longer name with `/mnt/` in it... Same share mounted twice (*using different permission/restrictions was just as I chose to; as browsers can be used to download from the web & thus less-trusted data*...)

Comment: re: save/upload... from a browser I think of SAVE instead of download, and thus said that instead of SAVE/UPLOAD, but for readers - that maybe DOWNLOAD/UPLOAD ... just my preferred word usage sorry.