# ffmpeg can't access file

Tags: permissions, ffmpeg, accessibility

I have seen this problem several times here or in other forums, usually user could not access the home folder. I have no problem with the home folder, ffmpeg works just fine there.
But in my folder on level / (/myFolder/) I can not make ffmpeg work.
So my command is:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i *.mkv -vf "hwdownload,format=nv12" -start_number 0 -vsync vfr -q:v 1 images/%07d.jpg
```

And the output is:

```
myVideo.mkv: No such file or directory
```

so it even resolves *.mkv to the actual video name. If I copy this video and the images folder to another location in my home folder and use the command there, it works like a charm.

For test purposes I already did several things which solved similar problems for other people

- snap install ffmpeg --devmode (version n4.3.1)
- chmod 777 -R /myFolder (I know it is a bad idea, this is a personal pc and I will change it again)
- chown myuser -R /myFolder
- went to the Ubuntu Software -> FFMPEG and activated all permissions
- execute ffmpeg with sudo

The error message did not change in any kind of way.
I use Ubuntu 18.04 with ffmpeg n4.3.1 installed via snap, I can't install it via apt since the version is too old and has no cuda support.

I am happy for every hint.

Comment: Confined snaps can only access $HOME, and if removable-media is flagged, also /media & /mnt, however other directories are not seen due to the restricted nature of confined snaps.  This is intentional; though Classic snaps do see your whole file-system (they run in a lower security model)   See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home for some clues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Chromium suddenly access any partition except for /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home)

Comment: If the snap isn't compiled to allow --devmode, you can't force it I believe.. which is what you're attempting  (and --devmode only works for *alpha* & *beta* channels  https://snapcraft.io/docs/channels)

Comment: @guiverc ohh I did not know that, I guess I will try to build a version from source then

Comment: Do not use `-i *.mkv`. **It will overwrite your files**. For example, the current directory contains `1.mkv`, `2.mkv`, `3.mkv`. The command `ffmpeg -i *.mkv output.foo` will actually execute as `ffmpeg -i 1.mkv 2.mkv 3.mkv output.foo`. This means `1.mkv` is the only input and all the rest of the `.mkv` files are interpreted as output files. [Use a for loop instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/).

Comment: Thank you @llogan, this was just an example, i created this folder for this file, this was the only file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like guiverc pointed out, apparently snap installed apps can only access $Home. Therefore I compiled and installed FFMPEG by myself, everything works fine now.