# Cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/var/www/snap/chromium/1732": mkdir /var/www/snap: permission denied

Tags: permissions, apache2, snap, chromium

I'm trying to launch the chromium-browser for my scraping project and I'm getting this error on my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-1038-aws x86_64)

> Chrome process stopped before startup completed. Additional info:
> /usr/bin/chromium-browser: 12: xdg-settings: not found
> cmd_run.go:1002: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot
> create "/var/www/snap/chromium/1732": mkdir /var/www/snap: permission
> denied Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently
> supported. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.

It works on my local machine and when run the `df` command to see mount points I could see that it's also similar to my local environment.
[click to see output of df command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1phlJ.png)

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: The error says that your home-dir isn't in /home/usr/... but in  /var/www/snap. Why is that ? /var/www/ should only be for web-server related stuff.

Comment: You're behind on upgrades; as a fully upgraded *focal* system will report itself as 20.04.3 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded ~fortnight before that date)

Comment: @SorenA my PHP project cloned inside that directory.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks. I just started developing on this server. Would it solve this issue after upgrade?

Comment: No; Chromium is a packaged as a *confined* snap, so has limited access outside of $HOME; yes you can add additional directories via `snap connect` (see an answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home) but no exceptions exist for /var/ which is a system directory.  That would require a *classic* confined snap

Comment: @DevinY The error text say's :"Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported." ...  and it is bad style to have development / projects in /var/www. Only copy / install necessary files there when deploying a new version of the project.