# Snap applications (Firefox and Chromium) snap cannot open folders mounted via sshfs

Tags: firefox, snap, chromium, 21.10, sshfs

Snap versions of Firefox and Chromium refuse to open folders and files mounted via sshfs while the same folder is normally browseable from the command line and from Gnome and the files can be opened in other applications (e.g., html files can be opened and edited in Gedit). While Chromium can browse the mounted folder and its subfolders, opening a file results in an "access denied" screen. Firefox refuses to open the directory completely (again, showing access denied). The remote folder is mounted to an empty folder in my home directory. Access to removable storage media is allowed in Ubuntu software center. Is there a solution to this?

I really need this kind of access to html files stored on a remote sshfs server. Running remote firefox over ssh with -X is possible but extremely slow. Copying the data locally every time I need to view it is not a solution for me (lots of data). Running a remote desktop session is an option, but not optimal (e.g., it is less comfortable with slow connection, when connection gets frequently interrupted, local printing and exporting html into local PDF copy is also less straightforward via VNC).

I want to stress again that the folder is mounted within the home directory and it is still not accessible. Is this a feature or a bug?

Thanks

Comment: Snap applications are sandboxed in a manner that allows them to access files only within a person's home directory. One option may be to mount the locations inside the home directory. Another would be to install the non-snap versions of Firefox and Chrome 

Comment: Snaps are run in *confined* spaces, which provides additional security, but also limits their access to the root file-system. You've provided no specifics as to directories you're trying to access (it maybe areas they cannot access due to confinement) OR if you need to enable via `snap connect`  - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home

Comment: The folder is mounted within the home directory (as already stated in the original post) and it is still not accessible. What else has to be done? Is non-snap Firefox going to be supported in future versions of Ubuntu?