# I can't upload any type or file (photo, vide, pdf, etc.) to social media or cloud servers with Brave browser

Tags: files, upload, brave

I'm new to Linux and today I encountered with this issue. I have been downloading files like photos, video, pdf no problem but now that I tried uploading files to Google Drive, Youtube and Twitter it won't let me, Drive and Youtube  tells me that my file is illegible and Twitter just says that an error has occurred.

I normally used Brave browser on Windows and never had this problem so I tried with Firefox and everything uploads correctly.

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; nor what package type of brave browser you've downloaded; as certain types of packages may have specific restrictions, eg. a *snap* package doesn't see your real file-system for security purposes except for specific directories; this improves your privacy, but can also mean you cannot upload files from those directories - but you've provided no specifics so we cannot know if you're encountering this or other issues.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and installed it via snap package.

Comment: Snap packages run *confined*, thus it matters where you have your files you want the browser to access; eg. https://askubuntu.com/a/1184374/469152 outlines a change that I noticed in 2019 when I started using `chromium` as a *snap* package instead of *deb* package.  I outline in that answer the `snap connect` command that adds /media & /mnt so it can be accessed via the *snap* package; the directory I wanted was elsewhere , but added a second mount as outlined there that met *snap* package requirements which still works today (now I'm on  *jammy* or what will be 22.04 on release)

Comment: Thanks, I actually visited Brave's webpage and it says on their Linux section that they recommend installing it from the terminal using commands instead of snap package and so I did, problem fixed.