# workarround to make snap apps able to access choosen paths

Tags: permissions, snap, directory

For 7zip, Open Office , Audacity and so much snap app, the applications haven't permissions enough to be able to read or save into the directories I choose in almost directories except default home directory.
This is embarassing because I habve to move big files from my /DATA to the ~/

Of course as session user I can do what I need into all those directories in ubuntu because of the permissions RWX I set to my session user ; I can also access to all my paths if I install those applications with the legacy way (without snap app manager)

Have you ever seen this and then which workarroud.

Thank you and nice week-end, Christophe FR

Comment: Only *classic* confined *snap* packages can access your root file-system, and they are limited as the default security is *strict* which allows access to /home/$USER ($HOME) and if `snap connect` is used also to `/media` and `/mnt` as well.  This is done by design for security reasons (why few apps are *classic* confined) - https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement

Comment: You'll never be able to let a general *snap* package use `/data` however you can provide mounts (*even secondary mounts as I've documented here in one answer somewhere*) in `/mnt` or `/media` to achieve what you want.. I use that myself with my preferred mount for my usual usage & a secondary mount in `/mnt` for *snap* packages  (my own use has more restrictions on the `/mnt` but that's as I prefer it - ie. optional)   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home

Comment: Snap access controls are governed by AppArmor rules *and* classic permissions. They must agree for the action to occur. You are not alone: This happens to be a time when many Snap developers and Desktop developers are looking at precisely this issue. They are working changes and default settings that balance access vs. security.

Answer (score 0):

The snap infrastructure is strict in that respect indeed. You will need to make your data available in a location for which a "connector" is available, i.e., a visible folder in your home folder, or a removable drive under /media/. There is currently no way out than to have your snap applications work with supported paths.

The most straightforward approach will be to directly mount your drive under one of these paths. However, linux also has the `mount --bind` facility. That way, you could bind partition mounted under, e.g., `/data/`, or any subdirectory of it, to a directory where your snap app has access.