# I don't seem to be able to download images from within snap packages

Tags: firefox, snap, downloads

I'm a fairly casual Linux user who's come back to Ubuntu for various reasons after using openSUSE for several years. A weird issue I've been running into is that, for some reason, anything that's installed as a snap can't download images, namely Firefox, Discord, and Chromium (the latter I only installed to test this). I directly downloaded a cross-distro Chromium build and it downloaded the ones I wanted with no issues.

To elaborate, what happens is that I open an image to download it, right-click (or ctrl+S, same result), select "Save Image As...", and then nothing happens. No download window opens and no file is downloaded without asking what to save it as. I couldn't actually find a browser other than Lynx that still runs from an apt package so I couldn't test whether that would work unfortunately.

Any help would be appreciated, especially with fixing this for Firefox in particular.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem. I can download images from snap-provided browsers just fine. Check your logs for error messages.

Comment: I don't see any Ubuntu OS/product/release details which may help, but you are aware *snap* packages run confined, thus they cannot access your whole file-system, only specific directories.  What the *snap* sees is only the *squashfs* that exists on disk, thus if you've got it set to save where it did last time, but have it pointed to a RO location issues can occur.  Given specifics as to what release, where you're trying to save etc.

Comment: I've written an answer here that maybe helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home but your issue maybe something else, as we're limited to knowing only the details you provide (that question is about `chromium` but it also relates to all *snap* packages & how the are built; ie. type of *confinement*)