# permissions after upgrade to ubuntu 22

Tags: upgrade, permissions, kubuntu, browser

I cannot save data from firefox (or another browser) to a folder for which I have write permissions, like folders inside my home, but I can save to home! As far as I can see I have the correct permissions but Firefox keeps saying I don't. chromium tells me the same.
This happened after the upgrade from 20 to 22.

Comment: You're asking about a Ubuntu Core 20 to Ubuntu Core 22 upgrade?   or 20.04 to 22.04?   Kubuntu doesn't support the *year* products (ie. 20 & 22)

Comment: Your details are vague, you mention `firefox` which is now a *snap* package, and also another *unstated* browser which makes me think of `chromium` now also *snap* packages. Those apps are now *confined* due to *snap* package which prevents them accessing the root file-system, but can access $HOME unless it's a symlink etc to another file-system, but you gave no specifics. I'll provide https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home/1184374#1184374 which may provide more details, but being specific can help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chromium in Ubuntu 22.04 and newer releases come as Snaps.

Snap packages can currently access your /home directory and (almost) nowhere else. The applications simply cannot access most of your filesystem. It's a feature of snap confinement (sandboxing). Researchers keep discovering vulnerabilities in browser software, so that confinement seems like a desirable feature for most users.

But that feature does, unfortunately, break access to outside-home directories.

You have options:

- You can modify your workflow: You can link to /home. Or you can sync to /home. The browsers cannot follow the link, but perhaps your other applications can. Or you can auto-sync between the locations.
- You can use a deb or upstream binary instead of the snap. They are still available.