# How can i install Blender from the Snap LTS channel?

Tags: software-center, snap, blender

When i try to install from the Softwarecenter, i got this error message:
**snap "blender" requires classic confinement**
What does this mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the classic mode of snap, and why do some snaps not install without it (e.g. MS Visual Studio)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917049/what-is-the-classic-mode-of-snap-and-why-do-some-snaps-not-install-without-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Blender page in SnapCraft store](https://snapcraft.io/blender) you have to execute the following command:

```
sudo snap install blender --channel=2.83lts/stable --classic
```

About *classic confinement* see [official documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement):

> A snap’s confinement level is the degree of isolation it has from your system. There are three levels of snap confinement:
> ...
>
> - **Classic**
>   Allows access to your system’s resources in much the same way traditional packages do. To safeguard against abuse, publishing a classic snap requires manual approval, and installation requires the --classic command line argument.