# How can a snap application use a port?

Tags: application-development, snap

I'm trying to package a web program as a snap, so I want to know how to enable it use any port, and how to allow the user to change port with some setting.

The software needs to access networks, the disk, ports, and `/etc`. I have solved the networking issue but not the others.

Thank you

Comment: I got, I can user classic mode

Comment: Good job solving your problem! You can answer your own question below to help future visitors.

Comment: A web program needing access to `/etc`? Do you mean an electron-one? [classic mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/917062/349837) give too much access. Its not enough with [network-interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/network-interface)?